# Check field for value or part of a value

Tags: excel

What function should I use to determine if a field contains a particular word ie.(Fail or Do not Load) and if so then set the value of a different column to = "Failure".  Please provide proper syntax.

Comment: Excel has a great library you can cycle through the list of functions and Excel will give you a quick synopsis of each.  What have you tried?  We are not Wikipedia.

Comment: I have tried index match but I am unsure what function to use to extract that portion of the text and if true the set the needed value.  Thought maybe contains or instr,however, not sure which would be the best and I am having difficulty with the proper syntax.

Comment: Look into Search or Find.  Try those then when you cannot make them work return with a test dataset and expected outcome and the formula that got you close.  This is not a code for me site.

Answer (score 0):

where YourLocation is A3 or some such.

=IFERROR(SEARCH("YourText",YourLocation),"Failure")

https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/search.php
https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/iserror.php

Comment: How do I use an or statement in the search criteria?   IFERROR(SEARCH("Fail" or "Do Not Load",B2),"Failure")

Comment: You would want to look into this.
https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-one-of-many-things